# integrability of function in open interval

Tags: calculus, integration

Can someone please explain why the function $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$$ is **not** integrable in the open interval $(0,1)$ but indeed integrable in the close form $[0,1]$?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think $\tfrac{1}{x}$ is integrable on $[0,1]$?

Comment: The Riemann integral isn't even defined on open intervals....

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\lim_{a\to 0}\ln a = -\infty$$

From this you can conclude that $f$ is neither integrable on the open nor on the closed interval.

Answer (score 0):

The key concept is that a single point has length (measure) zero, so adding or subtracting the extrema to an interval does not change the integral.  In your case all the two integrals does not exists.